# Variable in V-modal select box

Tags: javascript, select, vue.js, vuejs2

I'm having an array of objects. I wanted to change value to the object property by a select box.

HTML

```
<div id="app">
{{ message }}<br><br>
<select v-modal="items[0].val">
<option value="newjs">New js</option>
<option value="vannilajs">Vannila js</option>
</select>
<br>
ITEM 0 = {{items[0].val }}
<br>
ITEM 1 = {{items[1].val }}
</div>
```

JS

```
new Vue({
el:'#app',
data: {
message: 'testing',
items: [{val:'VUE'},{val: 'REACT'}] //intial two items    
   }
});
```

When select box changes I wanted to change the value of `ITEM 0` to Selected Value.

Just for testing purpose right now I'm trying to access 0th object from the array. This select box will be in v-for loop for multiple select box.

[FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/hw7xa4wy/)

Answer (score 2):

You can't assign variables to objects and arrays that easily in Vue.js

```
<div id="app">
    <select @input="change">
        <option value="newjs">New js</option>
        <option value="vannilajs">Vannila js</option>
    </select>
</div>

<script>
new Vue({
    el:'#app',
    data:{
        items:[{val:'VUE'},{val:'REACT'}]
    },
    methods: {
        change(element) {
            this.$set(this.items[0], 'val', element);
        }
    }
});
</script>
```

Vue can only migically refresh values changed by reference (`message = 'hey'`), or by object reference (`object.message = 'hey'`) but only if that reference was in `data()` in create time.

```
new Vue({
    data: {
      object: {first:0},
      array: [1,2,3]
    },
    methods: {
        change() {
            object.first = 2; // works
            object.second = 3; // doesn't work

            array[0] = 2; // works for 0,1,2
            array[4] = 3; // doesn't work
        }
    }
```

For the `object.second` and `array[3]` you need to use `$set()`.

Comment: Thanks +1 for another way. Why can't I assign values to objects that easily? the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/hw7xa4wy/1/) is working.

Comment: It is only working because you populated the array with indexes `0` and `1`. If you add values to `items` dynamically, it won't work.

Comment: But still I can assign values to dynamic data which could have been pushed to the array newly.

Answer (score 1):

Ok i misread your question. You do have a spelling mistake but you also need an intermediary variable to hold the value of the drop down

```
<div id="app">
{{ message }}<br><br>
<select v-model="selectedValue">
<option value="newjs">New js</option>
<option value="vannilajs">Vannila js</option>
</select>
<br>
ITEM 0 = {{selectedValue }}
<br>
ITEM 1 = {{items[1].val }}
</div>

new Vue({
el:'#app',
data: {
message: 'testing',
selectedValue: 'VUE',
items: [{val:'VUE'},{val: 'REACT'}] //intial two items    
   }
});
```

Comment: Great thanks Victor. Was pulling hair for more than 4 hour.

Comment: I don't need an intermediary variable. This is just the typo. check this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/hw7xa4wy/1/) Please update your answer to just spelling mistake.